# How to code options for a CYOA game(in Python)?

Tags: python

really new to python and stack overflow, and I'm currently trying out a choose your own adventure game. I'm already a bit familiar with if-else statements but I need a little help in a specific mechanic I want in the game. Basically, the character will have a certain set of choices so like:

```
print('[a]Wash the Dishes')
print('[b]Feed the Dog')
print('[c]Brush Teeth')
input = choice('What should I do? ')
```

So how could I make it that once the character inputs their choice, it'll show the same set of options, but now removing the one already selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
game_choice = {'a':"Wash the Dishes",'b':"Feed the Dog",'c':"Brush Teeth"}

# printing the choices to user
for key in game_choice:
    print(f"[{key}]: {game_choice[key]}")

# Iteratively asking user for input
while(len(game_choice)>0):
    choice = input('What should I do? ')
    if choice in game_choice:
        print(game_choice[choice])
        game_choice.pop(choice)
    else:
        print("You Entered wrong choice, Please try again")
```

Above we created a Dict() to store all the options and values in key pair groups.
You can use a similar approach to do build your game.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to answer! I would like to ask for clarification on a part in your sample code though. What is the use of the [while(len(game_choice) >0):] in determining the if-else statement? I'm quite new to python and I haven't really come across something like that before.

Comment: While iterates over variable game_choice and checks if the total number of values in game_choice is more than 0. If so, It will ask the user for input and whatever the user chooses, it will display the corresponding output. After that, it will remove that choice from game_choice. And it starts again from while block until game_choice becomes empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
choices = {'a': 'Wash the Dished', 'b': 'Feed the Dog', 'c': 'Brush teeth'}


def print_choices():
    for key in choices:
        print(f'[{key}]: {choices[key]}')
        # by using f'' you can use Curly Braces to call variables like what i did here
        # instead of doing .format or 'text' + variable + 'text'  or ...


def choice(txt):
    # your code
    input_value = input(txt)
    choices.pop(input_value, None)
    # None here causes the dict to NOT raise an error if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary


print_choices()

input_value = choice('What should I do? ')
```

This answer is based on considering you already know what a dictionary is in python.

Also if you wanted to have a message shown to the player if their input is not VALID you could do this instead:

```
def choice(txt):
    # your code
    input_value = input(txt)
    if input_value not in choices:
        print("Invalid Input")
    else:
        choices.pop(input_value)
```